# Submitting iPhone app with 2x on Ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, universal

How should i submit my iPhone app so that it is also available for downloads on iPad but with 2x thing on it.
I need some configuration settings...

*Architectures*: Standard/Optimized?

*Valid Architectures*: armv6 armv7....?

*Targeted Device Family*: ?

*iOS Deployment Target*: ?

```
Please also mention any other settings i've missed here.
```

Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iPhone/iPad for targeted device family, Standard (armv6/armv7) as architectures. Deployment target depends on the oldest iOS version you intend to support. I'd set it to 4.0 or 4.2 for new projects, but you could also use 3.2 (or even 3.0) if you're careful to use newer APIs only when they're available.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to do this, just submit the App as iPhone App and Apple will do the rest. Make you sure that in your build settings you have selected "iPhone" for "Target Device family".

Answer (score 0):

If you have an iPhone app and you want it to be presented in the iPhone size when run on the iPad where the iPad presents the user with a 2x option to make the iPhone app take up the full size of the iPad screen then you need to set your "Targeted Device Family" to iPhone in Xcode 4.2 under your project - build settings screen. -rrh